# FormShow in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I would like to know where is the formshow in delphi 2010 as when I can only see a formcreate in my project.

The reason I am asking is because I need to add Randomize in the FormShow event handler, as shown below:

```
procedure TfrmWinnaSpree.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Randomize;
end;
```

Comment: I don't get your question, but don't you want to use [`this way`](http://i.imgur.com/WPjGZ.jpg) ?

Comment: You can call Randomize in formcreate.

Comment: You have to write the method. Find OnShow in the object inspector and double click it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You create the event handler the same way you create almost every event handler in Delphi, by double-clicking the method in the `Events` tab of the `Object Inspector`.

Click on the form itself (not any control on the form), then switch to the `Object Inspector`. Click on the `Events` tab, and then scroll down to the `OnShow` event. Double-click in the right half next to the event name, and the IDE will create a new, empty event handler and put the cursor in the right place to start writing code.

[image: Object Inspector OnShow image]

```
procedure TForm3.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  |
end;
```

However, `FormShow` is the wrong place to call `Randomize`, because `FormShow` executes every time your form is shown, and that can happen more than once. Here's an example (it assumes two forms, *Form1* and *Form2*, autocreated as usual in the .dpr file with the default variable names, which of course is a bad idea - this is to demonstrate a problem with your question's purpose):

```
procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('In FormShow');
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2.Visible := not Form2.Visible;
end;
```

Run the program and click `TForm1.Button1` multiple times; you'll see the *In FormShow* message every other time you do so.

The proper places for a call to *Randomize* are:

- in your main form's *FormCreate*
- in an initialization section of your main form's unit

  ```
  unit uMainForm;

  interface

    ...

  implementation

    ...

  initialization 

  Randomize;

  end.
  ```
- in your project source (.dpr) file

  ```
  program MyGreatApp;

  uses
    Math,
    Vcl.Forms,
    uMainForm in 'uMainForm.pas' {Form1};

    {$R *.RES}

  begin
    Randomize;
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
    Application.Title := 'My Super App';
    Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
    Application.Run;
  end.
  ```

Comment: Thanks Ken. Your explanation helped alot.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can also override the protected method TForm.DoShow:

```
type
  TForm = class(Forms.TForm)
  protected 
    procedure DoShow; override;
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm.DoShow;
begin.
  // custom show code
  inherited;
  // custom show code
end;
```

The advantage over the event-based approach is that you can put your custom code before or after the inherited call.

Comment: In order for there to be an advantage, DoShow needs to do something more than just fire the event. Does it?

Comment: Yes and only if the custom code has to be be executed before the inherited call, otherwise if the custom code is placed after then it's quite similar to the event assignement. But people often forget that they can also override the methods in a simple TForm project and this complementary answer has only been posted because of this.

Comment: Yes what? Does DoShow do more than fire the event?

Comment: OK. I've forgot to check what was containing the inherited method...but stop blaming me, my answer was also conceptual: don't forget that you can override instead of abusing of events.